# Initialise NSDictionary with two keys, values

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create a list of parameters that I need to pass to a 3rd-party library. The object needs to be a NSDictionary object. I am very new to Objective-C/iOS development.

```
NSDictionary* parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:
                     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"parameter1",@"parameter2", nil]
            forKeys: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:"value1", "value2", nil]];
```

The code compiles correctly, but the debugger stops at this line with the following message "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Before, since I only needed one parameter, was using this line and worked fine.

```
NSDictionary* parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:phoneNumber forKey:@"parameter1"]
```

Any other alternatives that I could use for more than one parameter?

Comment: Yep, arrayWithObjects isn't real happy with `char*` input pointers.  (Likely there was a compiler warning.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the keys and values backward. It's much easier to use modern syntax:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{ @"parameter1" : @"value1", @"parameter2" : @"value2" };`.
```

And as Wain pointed out, you have C-strings, not `NSString` objects for your values.

Comment: Thank you, this worked alright. It is a lot easier with the newer syntax!

Answer (score 4):

This line:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:"value1", "value2", nil]
```

Is wrong and should be:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1", @"value2", nil]
```

You should also check the order of the parameters (you look to have got the keys and values the wrong way around).

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained the problem with your code as written.

Another point, though: You are using perhaps the most verbose, awkward syntax for creating a dictionary. With the advent of Objective C 2.0, you can use a much more compact syntax:

NSDictionary* parameters = @{
  @"parameter1": @"value1",
  @"parameter2": @"value2"};

This syntax uses the more intuitive key:value ordering.

Do a search on "Objective C literals" to find out more.

Comment: Yup. It looks like our answers "crossed in the mail"